# How to write php logic if no files were uploaded

Tags: php

I wanted to do a update profile page. When user uploads a picture, it will update to the database and change the `$_SESSION['profilepic']` .However, if a user does not want to update its profile image and not change the database value but change other data only. How do i write the logic, if 'file were not uploaded, update other value except the image and not change the session', since I'm not able to place the stored img at input file value to ensure the images in database stays and not updated

This is my php code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['profile_update_btn']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $profimage = $_FILES['profileimage']['name'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phonenum'];

    $query = "UPDATE students SET fullName='$fullname',email = '$email', phoneNum='$phone', profilePic='$profiimage'  WHERE email = '$username'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profileimage"]["tmp_name"],"prof/".$_FILES["profileimage"]["name"]);
        $_SESSION['profilepic'] = $profimage;
        $_SESSION['success']= "Profile Updated";
        header('Location: user_profile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status']= "Profile Not Updated";
        header('Location: user_profile.php');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file, you `$_FILES` are filled with values in an array with the key of the name of file field.

```
  'profileimage' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
```

The actual values could be something like:

```
  'profileimage' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'v35.doc' (length=7)
      'type' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => string 'F:\wamp64\tmp\php37EA.tmp' (length=25)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 45568
```

**Therefore you could do your logic like this:**

```
if (empty($_FILES['profileimage']['name'])) {
    //Do whatever you want when no upload...
}
```